# Access Denied Exception when build with docker on kuberentes with jenkins pipeline (ubuntu server)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, jenkins, cicd

I am using Jenkins pipeline to deploy docker image on Kubernetes (minikube) this error is thrown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRZPS.png)

Starting Kubernetes deployment

```
ERROR: ERROR: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:62)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:53)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:182)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.BaseClient.<init>(BaseClient.java:55)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient.<init>(DefaultKubernetesClient.java:91)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientWrapper.<init>(KubernetesClientWrapper.java:78)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesDeployContext$ClientWrapperFactoryImpl.buildClient(KubernetesDeployContext.java:466)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.doCall(DeploymentCommand.java:141)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.call(DeploymentCommand.java:122)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.call(DeploymentCommand.java:105)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1288)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand.execute(DeploymentCommand.java:67)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand.execute(DeploymentCommand.java:46)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.runCommand(CommandService.java:88)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.execute(CommandService.java:96)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.executeCommands(CommandService.java:75)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.BaseCommandContext.executeCommands(BaseCommandContext.java:77)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesDeploy.perform(KubernetesDeploy.java:42)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.SimpleBuildStepExecution.run(SimpleBuildStepExecution.java:54)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.SimpleBuildStepExecution.run(SimpleBuildStepExecution.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /root/.minikube/ca.crt
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:371)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:422)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3206)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.CertUtils.getInputStreamFromDataOrFile(CertUtils.java:65)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.CertUtils.createTrustStore(CertUtils.java:71)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.SSLUtils.trustManagers(SSLUtils.java:115)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.SSLUtils.trustManagers(SSLUtils.java:94)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:76)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: can you share more details please. Which OS are you on. Which user are you using to start the minikube pods

Comment: I have solve this issue as i do move the required files to an accessible place then restart jenkins server

Answer (score 0):

In the /.kube/config file there is a users section right at the end. I changed it from the default user name minikube to a real username on my minikube server.

- name: minikube

TO

- name: ubuntu